# jqGrid recordtext Customization

Tags: jqgrid

I need to customize the `recordtext: "{0} - {1} of {2}"` in the jqGrid jQuery plugin.

In my project I am using several jqGrids, and I want to change the text inside the parenthesis for each grid -- I need them to look like these:

```
1-10 of 29 (Users) 
1-10 of 29 (Administrators) 
1-10 of 29 (Emails)
```

The default `recordtext` in jqGrid's language file (`i18n/grid.locale-en.js`) is:

```
recordtext: "{0} - {1} of {2}"
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
$("#grid").jqGrid('setGridParam', { recordtext: "View {0} - {1}" + " of " + Total}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use extend method on language script before the creating grid.

```
jQuery.extend($.jgrid,{
    defaults : {
        recordtext: "View {0} - {1} of (Users) {2}",
        emptyrecords: "No records to view",
        loadtext: "Loading...",
        pgtext : "Page {0} of {1}"
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your jqgrid definition just override the recordtext parameter.
For example, this is what I did.

```
  $myGrid = $('gridName)'
        .jqGrid(
                {
                    dataType   : 'json',
                    scroll : true,
                    scrollOffset : 20,
                    scrollrows : true,
                    viewsortcols : [ true, 'horizontal', true ],
                    width : '100%',
                    height : '100%',
                    viewrecords : true,
                    recordtext: "Total Records : {2}",
            ....other parameters as you need them..
        });
```

Please refer the [jqgrid-wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a work around like this:

In the **gridcomplete** function of jqgrid explicitly add your desired text to the right pager td.  The generated td id of the pager section will be, 'pager_right'.(You can confirm it with firebug).

```
 gridComplete: function ()
                {

                    var tableData = $( '#pager_right' ).find( 'div' );
                    span = $( '<span>(some text)</span>' );
                    tableData.append( span );
                 }
```