# Jqgrid How to store a parameter as variable to reuse it in html element

Tags: javascript, html, jqgrid

I have a Jqgrid :

```
<input type="button" name="htmlbutton" id="htmlbutton" value="">

<table id="jqGrid" ></table>
    <div id="jqGridPager"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

        var MaingridQueryResults_1 = {{available_lessons|safe}};
        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
            datatype: 'local',
            data: MaingridQueryResults_1,
            colModel: [
                {name: 'id', label: 'id',  align:'left', hidden: true, width:30,},
                {name: 'phone', label: 'Société', align:'left', width:90},
                {name: 'last_name', label: 'Nom', align:'left', width:80},
                {name: 'first_name', label: 'Prénom', align:'left', width:60},
            ],
            width: window.innerWidth-50, 
            height: 300, 
            pager: "#jqGridPager", 
            pginput: false,
            pgbuttons: false,     
            pgtext: null,         
            viewrecords: true, // WANT TO PUT THIS VALUE INSIDE htmlbutton 
            recordtext: "{2} Results",
            toppager: true,
        });
```

I modified parameter `recordtext: "{2} Results"` to display the number of rows of the main grid into the bottom pager thanks to this link :
[jqGrid recordtext Customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659109/jqgrid-recordtext-customization)

I would like to be able to copy this `{2}` parameter value and store it somewhere so I can reuse it in a standard html button or label as value.

How can I do this ?

Comment: I edited the question and add my Jqgrid code so it's more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I finally achieve what i wanted :

```
<span id="htmlspan" name="htmlspan"></span>

function getSearchNumbers() {
                var grid = $("#jqGrid");
                var rslt = grid.getGridParam("records");
                document.getElementById('htmlspan').innerHTML = "Results : " + rslt;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get that value when the grid is completed:

```
loadComplete: function () {
  var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam");
  var text = p.recordtext;
  let reg = /\{(.*?)\}/;
  let match = text.match(reg);
  $('#htmlbutton').val(match[1]);
}
```

Comment: Your answer return "2" but what i want is the value of {2}  wich should be the number of rows in the grid , not just 2 as integer or text.

Comment: match[0] for "{2}"

Answer (score 0):

To create a custom attribute you have to follow the pattern where your attribute should start with **data-***.

In this example I created custom attribute on  where ***value*** attribute is not present by default.

```
<div class="grid" data-recordtext="custom text" id="recordtext"></div>
<input type="button" name="htmlbutton" id="htmlbutton" value="">

<script>
    $('#htmlbutton').val($('#recordtext').val());
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my question was more about how to get the recordtext: "{2} Results" value in JQGRID and store it into a VAR. So unless I'm missing something that's not what I'm looking for ...